# Are all node-to-node and node-to-client mini-protocols available both over a network socket and a local socket?

Tags: cardano-node

There doesn't seem to be any cli flags available for cardano-node to run a subset of them.

Also, can the "locations" at where the mini-protocols are run be configured with the `--socket-path` and `--host-addr`/`--port` flags? I.e, when not specifying any of them, the mini-protocols won't be served over that method?